# How to build an Array of Array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My output should be like this: (eg. data)

```
myArray = [ [otherArray0], [otherArray1], [otherArrayN] ]
```

My try:

```
var myArray = [];
var num = 50;
for (i=0; i<num;i++)
{

    var a = 0;
    $('#divID .class select[value!=""]').each(function() //get values from a select
    {
        var otherArray+i = []; //each for cycle is a new "sub array"
        otherArray+i[a] = $(this).val(); //store in array the values from select
        a++
     })
}
```

Am I thinking well?

Comment: `var myArray[i] = array ();` should be `var myArray[i] = [];`

Comment: @AdamRackis, ty, ive updated

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to get. You don't put the names of arrays in other arrays, you put the arrays themselves. What do you want the resulting data to look like?

Comment: @Barmar, The output should be: `myArray[[otherArray1],[otherArray2],[otherArrayN]]`where each otherArray has diferent values stored.

Comment: That's not possible output. Do you mean `[["otherArray1"],["otherArray2"], ...]`?

Comment: I mean myArray `[[otherArray1],[otherArray2],[otherArrayN]]`, where for eg. otherArray1 is `[1,2,3,4,5,N]` . Not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly

```
otherArray[i] = []; // create a new array
```

Then

```
otherArray[i][a] = $(this).val();
```

But your code can be made a lot simpler

```
var myArray = [];
var num = 50;
for (i=0; i<num;i++)
{
    myArray.push($.map($('#divID .class select[value!=""]'),function(e){
        return e.val();
    }));
}
```

Comment: could it be `otherArray+i[i][a] = $(this).val();` ? That `+i` its just to create diferent arrays

Comment: @skdnewbie = `otherArray+i` makes no sense and is a syntax error as you cant add an integer and Array

Comment: look at this: `otherArray1[1,2,3,4]`, `otherArray2[6,7,8,9]` and final should be `myArray[[otherArray1],[otherArray2]]`

Answer (score 2):

A pattern of setting up an empty array (`[]`) then using `push` to fill it as you go, then `push`ing the array onto your final array should take you far.

```
var myArray = [];
for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    var otherArray = [];
    $(/*...*/).each(function()
    {
       var val = /*...*/;
       otherArray.push(val);
    });
    myArray.push(otherArray);
}
```

Comment: Hum, Ill try this! Looks like what I want

Comment: The output should be: `myArray[[otherArray1],[otherArray2],[otherArrayN]]`where each otherArray has diferent values. Your code will do it ?

Comment: @skdnewbie Yes. It produces an array of arrays, i.e. `[ [], [], [], [] ]`

Answer (score 1):

Reading between lots of lines, I think this is what you want:

```
var myArray = [];
$("#divID .class select").each(function() {
    var subarray = [];
    $("option[value!='']", $(this)).each(function() {
        subarray.push($(this).val());
    });
    myArray.push(subarray);
}
```

`myArray` will then contain:

```
[[sel1Opt1, sel1Opt2, sel1Opt3, ...], [sel2Opt1, sel2Opt2, sel3Opt3, ...], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 50;
for (i=0; i<num;i++)
{
var myArray[i] = array ();
var a = 0;
$('#divID .class select[value!=""]').each(function() //get values from a select
{
    myArray[i].push( $(this).val()); //store in array the values from select

})
}
```